# MySQL dependent subqueries when should be independent

Tags: mysql, optimization

when I explain this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.mail)
FROM ep_point_transactions pt
  JOIN ep_transaction_status ts ON ts.tid = pt.tid
  JOIN users u ON u.uid = pt.uid
WHERE ts.anulada IS NULL
  AND pt.anulada IS NULL
  AND ts.source = 'rake'
  AND (pt.educapuntos * pt.multiplicador) >= 7500
  AND ts.timestamp < '2010-11-30 23:00:00'
  AND pt.uid NOT IN (
    SELECT distinct(pt2.uid)
    FROM ep_point_transactions pt2
      JOIN ep_transaction_status ts2 ON ts2.tid = pt2.tid
    WHERE ts2.anulada IS NULL
      AND pt2.anulada IS NULL
      AND ts2.source = 'rake'
      AND ts2.timestamp > '2010-11-30 23:00:00'
  );
```

I'm obtaining this output:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ts    | ref    | PRIMARY,source | source  | 194     | const                   | 2997 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | pt    | ref    | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | educapoker.ts.tid       |   30 | Using where                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | educapoker.pt.uid       |    1 |                              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ts2   | ref    | PRIMARY,source | source  | 194     | const                   | 2997 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pt2   | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 8       | educapoker.ts2.tid,func |    1 | Using where                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

My doubt here is why MySQL is considering the subquery dependent if I can execute it isolately.

As far as I know, in a dependent subquery, MySQL executes the subquery once for each parent query row, so it can be really inefficient.

Can anyone bring me some light here, please?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you move the subquery to your where clause?

Comment: MySQL performs better filtering in FROM clause. The problem here is that the optimizer is executing the subquery once per each result (thousands), because it's is considering the subquery as being dependent of the main one. This is making the server enter in a never-ending execution.

Comment: This is a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63701) in MySQL. It is fixed starting from MySQL 5.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the `NOT IN(SELECT ...)`. Try rewriting it to `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
  tid
FROM 
  ep_transaction_status ts
LEFT JOIN 
  ep_transaction_status ts2
USING (tid)
WHERE 
  ts.anulada IS NULL 
  AND ts.source = 'rake'
  AND ts2.anulada IS NULL
  AND ts2.timestamp > '2010-11-30 23:00:00'
  AND ts2.tid IS NULL
```

Which BTW seems to me to be same as

```
SELECT 
  tid
FROM 
  ep_transaction_status ts
WHERE 
  ts.anulada IS NULL 
  AND ts.source = 'rake'
  AND ts.timestamp <= '2010-11-30 23:00:00'
```

Comment: Good approach, thank you! Mi query was not doing what I expected, so I have had to rewrite it again. But using your approach is much more efficient. Thank you again.

Comment: BTW, still don't understand why is the NOT IN making the subquery dependent.

Comment: It's a known issue with MySQL's oprimizer. It's been supposedly fixed in MySQL 5.4, but I didn't have time to check that yet.

Comment: I've been investigating this issue. It's is suggested in this [link](http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/752847/dependent_subquery/correlated_subquery.html) that you can reproduce the expected performance of the optimizer by creating a temporary table, populating it with the subquery results, and JOINing (or LEFT JOINing) with the main query. This is a disgusting multi-step solution, but I've followed this path. As soon as I update my MySQL version I'll report back.

Comment: `[LEFT] JOIN`ed subqueries are essentialy temporary tables anyway.

Comment: I think I'll edit my post and show the final query to make the problem more comprehensive.